# Unable to boot into Ubuntu 20.04.1, after installing along side Win 10

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I just installed Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS however the laptop boots up in Windows 10 without any option to boot into Ubuntu. I am newbie and do not get much technical side of things – is there anything that could help explain in simple language as to how I can fix the issue please ?

Below is the current boot order
Yes, see below is the ‘UEFI Boot Order’
USB Flash Drive/USB Hard disk
OS boot manager
USB cd/dvd rom drive
! network Adapter

Secure boot is disabled.

Comment: You can use boot-repair to solve issues https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair